# Doxygen not extracting all files

Tags: doxygen

I am using doxygen to doxygenate a project that I am currently working on.
My problem is that Doxygen is not extracting any documentation for my .hh files and the classes in them, only for main.cc.
All my .hh files and my main.cc are in the same folder where i have my doxyfile. all my .hh have

```
/** @file name.hh
    @brief whatever
*/
```

and they also have all the `#include"some_header_file.hh"` that they need to have.
my headerfiles are classes, so I also have

```
/** @class class_name
    @brief whatever
*/
```

and all methodes are commented.

In my main file I also have its corresponding `@file` and `@brief`.

My doxyfile input configuration is the following one:

```
INPUT                  = "."
INPUT_ENCODING         = utf-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = main.cc \ *.hh
RECURSIVE              = NO
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = *~
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
```

and yes, I also have EXTRACT_ALL = YES.

When I execute `doxygen doxyfile` it prints, at the end,
lookup cache used 1/65536 hits=0 misses=1
finished...

The result that I get has no information about my files except for main.cc.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is that `FILE_PATTERNS` on one line in your actual Doxyfile or two?

Comment: What happens if you change `FILE_PATTERNS` to just `*.hh` (no `main.cc`, no ``\``)

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, they are in the same line. Trying what you said gave me the output for all my .hh files.

Comment: The backslash is used by Doxygen as a line-continuation character.  It should be removed when your configuration isn't split across multiple lines.  Try `FILE_PATTERNS = main.cc *.hh` without the backslash.

Comment: @BenVoigt it actually worked! Thank you. Would you mind posting your comment as answer for me to accept it?